# Add component every time actionPerformed is called

Tags: java, swing

Hello guys I've been trying to do a small program which is just a window with a `JButton` that opens a `JOptionPane` on click and lets me input an entry for a vacation list. I want to add that entry as an `JCheckBox` to the `JLabel` every time the action of the `JButton` is performed. My problem currently is that even though my code seems so work the `JCheckBox` won't show up after inputting the String into the `JOptionPane`. It probably has to do something with `actionPerformed` being a void method? I'd be glad for some help and I'm sorry if that question has already occurred but I didn't find it anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

My Code:

```
public class Urlaub extends JFrame {

    public Urlaub() {
        super("Urlaub");
        JFrame window = this;
        window.setSize(800, 600);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);

        JLabel grouped = new JLabel();
        window.add(grouped);

        grouped.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton addThing = new JButton("Add things");
        addThing.setVisible(true);
        grouped.add(addThing);
        addThing.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String entry = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter item");
                JCheckBox checkItem = new JCheckBox(entry);
                grouped.add(checkItem); // this is the line which should add the JCheckBox to the JLabel/Window 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `revalidate` the container after changing it's children.  This forces a repaint.

You're also adding the elements to a `JLabel`, which is unusual.  You're better off with a `JPanel`:

```
        super("Urlaub");
        JFrame window = this;
        window.setSize(800, 600);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);

        JPanel grouped = new JPanel();
        window.getContentPane().add(grouped);
        grouped.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton addThing = new JButton("Add things");
        grouped.add(addThing);
        grouped.add(new JCheckBox("je"));
        addThing.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String entry = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter item");
                JCheckBox checkItem = new JCheckBox(entry);
                grouped.add(checkItem); // this is the line which should add the JCheckBox to the JLabel/Window#
                window.getContentPane().revalidate();
            }
        });
```